# Insert the content of column in many csv files in one list R

Tags: r

I want to read the content of the column defined as an input of my function , from different csv files I use the following function

```
Getmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332)
{
  i<- 1
  filenames <- sprintf("%0.3d", id)

  Data <- list()

  for (filename in filenames) 
  {


    Data[i]  <- read.csv(file= filename, sep=",", colClasses=c(pollutant))

     i <- i++

  }

  result <- mean(Data ,na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Error: unexpected '}' in:
"
  }"

> result <- mean(Data ,na.rm = TRUE)
>   Error in mean(Data, na.rm = TRUE) : object 'Data' not found
>   }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

any idea how to fix this, this is my first steps in R

Comment: Not sure i++ works that way in r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the use of `data.table::fread` an option?

first, get a list of files you wish to read using `list.files()`

```
fileslist <- list.files( 
  path = "./", 
  pattern = "(^[0-3]\\d\\d|^4[0-3]\\d|^44[0-4]).csv$",  # regex to select 000.csv to 444.csv
  full.names = TRUE )
```

Then use fread to read to a list, only keeping the "pollutant"-column, usign the `select`-argument of the function.

```
library( data.table )
contents <- lapply( fileslist, fread, select = c( "pollutant" ) )
```

then perform the desired mean-operation on this list...

`sapply( contents, mean, na.rm = TRUE )`

Comment: how to keep the "%0.3d" , my files names fromm 001.csv, till 444.csv. I use Id to get the files needed only

Comment: @Ali adapt the `pattern`-argument in `files.list()`. see updated answwer...

Answer (score 1):

R doesn't have the operand `++` as you use it, so it's waiting for the second argument that needs to follow a +. Replace with `i=i+1`.

Comment: thanks a lot , now I get Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
 any idea how to fix this too please  my files looks like 001.csv, ...., 444.csv

Comment: Hard for me to tell. Can you provide the `head(filenames)`? But I can already tell you that's not how colClasses works.